# Font Awesome not displaying properly in hosted asp application

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, fonts, font-awesome

We have used font awesome in our application. When the application is hosted onto IIS, we are unable to see proper font.
Otherwise running via Visual Studio gives proper fonts.

```
<link href="assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="assets/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="assets/css/style-metro.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="assets/css/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="assets/css/themes/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="style_color"/>
<link href="assets/plugins/uniform/css/uniform.default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

This is the section from master page file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following lines to Web.Configs system.WebServer tag worked.

```
<staticContent>
   <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
</staticContent>
```

Comment: Could you mark your question as answered if you've solved it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that or alternatively register the MIME TYPES in IIS. If you are an admin, you can register it at a server level and all sites will work. A reboot of the site or IIS is required. In that case, remove the explicit registration from your web.config file.